# Qt/C++ Not displaying QGraphicview as QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, draw, qgraphicsview, qwidget

My project consists of operations between geometric figures on a cartesian plane.I would include a graph that have to be updated after each operation.

Thats the source:

http://pastebin.com/s5Fu9dHJ

I've created the wrapper "disegna" (: public QWidget) because of I am sending to display everything as separate widgets (I have a widget for the virtual keyboard, another for Qlineedits, etc.) and I need an QWidget object can be used with view-> addWidget (QWidget,int,int) because I cannot pass directly a QMainWindow object.

The Program run with no errors,but no "hello world" is drawed (and no blank-space for istance QGraphicView is created).

where am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
QGraphicsView view(&scene);
view.show();
```

to

```
QGraphicsView * view = new QGraphicsView(&scene);
view->show();
```

The way you have it now, the instance of `QGraphicView` is allocated on the stack and gets destroyed right after the `disegna` constructor is executed, that's why you can't see it.

Don't forget to free the memory.

Comment: Thank you,I am so tired that I forget that.It runs ok but there are 2 windows (one as before and the new one with the QGraphicview istance).How can I include this one as a QWidget on the MAIN layout?

Comment: Solved!
This is the final source to display my QGraphicView into a QMainWindow

disegna::disegna(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) {

    scene.addText("19 11");
    QGraphicsRectItem* myrect = scene.addRect(QRectF(0,0,50,50),QPen(), QBrush());
    scene.setForegroundBrush(QBrush(Qt::blue, Qt::CrossPattern));
    scene.addRect(QRectF(0, 0, 700, 300));

    QGraphicsView * view = new QGraphicsView(&scene,this);
    view->show();
}

Thank you again
Now i could go to bed (12hours of study!)